# CCCONE.EXE continuously crashes

Tags: windows, crash

I work for an IT service company and I have one client who is a body shop and uses an application called CCC One. Our RMM software keeps getting alerts about their application crashing. We have an updater on the server that ensures all of the applications are up to date. Any recommendations?

Application crashes found:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Name: Application Error
Error Message: Faulting application name: CCCONE.exe, version: 35.0.0.5080, time stamp: 0x645969af
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2965, time stamp: 0xf18c1c30
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0013d6c2
Faulting process id: 0x413c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d99d541dbdafc2
Faulting application path: C:\ProgramData\CCCIS\CCCONE\v2453\CCCONE.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: fcd37a9b-4086-4378-8a87-953e89103e41
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
TimeWritten: 6/12/2023 1:34:24 PM
ComputerName: GPAB-GIL-SHOP01
Category: 100
Type: Error
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, and professional IT support is probably off-topic here... But the 35.0.0.5080 version doesn't sound like it's the latest one (see https://cccis.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/15316623753492-CCC-ONE-Repair-Facilities-release-36-0-0-5050) so a good start might be to have them install the latest version

Comment: But regardless, this is a bug/error in the CCC One application and it needs to be taken care with this software vendor